# List all possible combinations for a vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, combinations, permutation

So say I have a vector `[1 0]`, I want to list all the possible combinations of the numbers in that vector that fit into a `1x3` vector. i.e.
`[1 1 1] [1 1 0] [1 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 1] [0 1 1] [1 0 1] [0 1 0]`.

I have done this (here is the [link](http://pastebin.com/feWn9sts)), but my function is very slow when I go to do things in the 10th dimension.
That is when I run `combos([1 0],10)`, it takes a few minutes to do.

I was wondering if matlab had basically a function that already do that (similar to `perms` or `nchoosek`), or if someone has a faster method than what I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a very interesting way to ask for a way to generate binary numbers between 0 and 2^n-1 (n=number of digits or length of vector)

```
dec2bin(0:2^n-1)=='1'
```

For the more general case, where you have another vector than `[0,1]` use [`all_comb`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33495-all-combinations/content//all_comb.m) from matlab file exchange:

```
all_comb([0,1],n)
```

Comment: that works, but can you explain what does `dec2bin` does there?

Comment: @asosnovsky What you want is the binary expansion of all numbers from `0` to `2^n-1`. That's why `dec2bin` achieves your desired result

Answer (score 3):

You can abuse [**`de2bi`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/de2bi.html) :

```
n = 3;
out = de2bi(0:(2^n)-1)
```

Requires the **Communications Systems Toolbox** though. If you don't have it, go for [**Daniel's Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32029323/2605073).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also do

`combvec([1 0],[1 0],[1 0])`

Not sure if this is faster than what is suggested above.. Hope this helps.